# Unable to connect to AWS DAX

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am getting this error when I execute my lambda, it
raises `DaxClientError('Failed to configure cluster endpoints from {}'.format(seeds), DaxErrorCode.NoRoute)`

I am trying to connect to my DAX cluster from Amazon Lambda (written in python).
I have installed amazon-dax-client to a folder, placed my lambda file there, made package and uploaded as zip file when i test lambda it throws above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lamda function needs to be in the same VPC as the DAX cluster. Otherwise, it won't be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post on [using Amazon DAX from AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-increase-performance-while-reducing-costs-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-accelerator-dax-and-aws-lambda/). The sample code is for NodeJS but the Lambda/VPC configuration applies no matter what language is used.

Comment: Yes, this blog post is super helpful, actually i was able to fix the problem by making dax cluster and lamda in the same VPC

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add to your "security groups" inbound rules to allow TCP port 8111